# Child ImageView Captures OnClickListener instead of parent Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

In XML, I have implemented a Linear Layout with a horizontal scrollview with scrollable text and an imageview with a drawable vector (copy to clipboard vector).

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="30dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_new"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/copy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="-3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="-3dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">


        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:clickable="false">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gen"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text "
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:clickable="false"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pos"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:scaleX="-1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_copy"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"
            android:clickable="false"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Length"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Long Text Sample"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/pwSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:max="128"
        android:min="8"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

In Java I have implemented an onclicklistener for the parent LinearLayout containing the scrollview and the imageview.

Java

```
copyclipboard = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.copy);


        copyclipboard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clipboard = (ClipboardManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                clip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", gen.getText());
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

The issue I'm facing is that the onclicklistener isn't responsive when clicked on over 90% of the area and works only when the area which imageview (ID pos) covers. How do I tackle this issue?

Comment: I think , your onclick method is taking some time. Debug it if its called and takes time in executing.

Comment: @ROHITLIEN no, it's fast. It takes a few ns to execute the command. The onlick is unresponsive on the layout, it can't be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your horizontal view is consuming all the clicks. Either remove the horizontal scroll view and work with marquee in text view or you can write your own horizontal scroll view. Hope it helps